# Help with pine stairs

Tags: stairs

Moved into a house with a pine staircase, it appears that the previous owners were in the middle of finishing/refinishing the steps (some stairs appear to have a clear coat and others appear to be just sanded.) We would like to save the steps(stain),but unsure how to proceed. Any and all help/advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you happy with the color on the clear coated steps or do you want a different color for all?

Comment: The color already on steps looks to be clear with orange undertones. Not my favorite, but if I have no other choice, id have to stick with it

Comment: It comes to me that previous owners got some of these steps damaged/cracked and just before selling it to You they changed them.

Answer (score 1):

I would sand all of these steps and give one same finish for all. That would give them same look that You could choose by Yourself. With proper equipement and little time it can be done in few hours plus time for hardening for any finish.
*I lack proper English vocabulary, so I will not go into specific terms. I bet anyone from some big store will help You to choose proper materials/equipement.*